# Non-gaussian ML estimation with auto.arima in R

Tags: r, time-series, maximum-likelihood, arima, normality-assumption

I am struggling with the details of the `auto.arima` function in R. Particularly, I would like to estimate an ARIMA model with errors (i.e. regressors) for which:

- the dependent variable in first difference is stationary and normal;
- the two independent variables (errors) are first difference stationary, but not normal.

My questions are:

- is the default log-likelihood for the AIC in `auto.arima` Gaussian? Or is it empirical maximum likelihood?
- what about the method specification? ("ML" and "CSS" are the alternatives. I would really try to use ML for the hyperparameter estimation, but I am afraid the results would be biased for the coefficients of the regressors, because of non-gaussianity of the independent variables).

Thank you in advance!

Edits:

By "two independent variables (errors)" I mean a model as suggested by Rob Hyndman here: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/ (Regression with ARMA errors)
For example, considering an ARMA(2,0) with $x_t$ and $z_t$ errors, the model would be the following:
$$y_t=\beta_1x_t+\beta_2z_t+n_t$$
$$n_t=\phi_1n_{t-1}+\phi_2n_{t-2}+z_t$$
Since the phi coefficients are estimated on a normal time series with MLE, it should be fine. My doubt is what concerns the tho beta coefficients, as they are as well estimated by a ML estimator, on non - normal data.

Comment: The model for the differenced dependent variable $\Delta y_t=:x_t$ is ARMA(p,q):$$x_t=c+\varphi_1 x_{t-1}+\dots+\varphi_p x_{t-p}+\varepsilon_t+\theta_1\varepsilon_{t-1}+\dots+\theta_q\varepsilon_{t-q}.$$What do you mean by *two independent variables (errors)*? There is only one variable $x_t$ and the error term $\varepsilon_t$ with their lags. Also, given the above equation, you might need to think about whether $x_t$ can be normal when $\varepsilon_t$ is nonnormal. For example, conditionally on $x_{t-1},\dots,x_{t-p},\varepsilon_{t-1},\varepsilon_{t-q}$ it is not possible.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the post, so maybe now it is more clear.

Comment: According to my reading of Hyndman's blog post you linked to, the model you have written is ARMAX, not regression with ARMA errors. Meanwhile, `auto.arima` fits regression with ARMA errors. Also, the distributional assumption of a maximum likelihood estimator is on the error term, not on any of the variables. So as long as errors are normal, a normality-based MLE will be fine.

Comment: $x_t$ and $z_t$ are not errors, they are variables. $\varepsilon_t$ are errors.

Comment: Edited, thanks! The problem is the residuals aren't gaussian as well. From my understanding, MLE should follow these steps: 1) identify the distribution of a variable; 2) compute the log - likelihood; 3) estimate the coefficients. Hence, the distribution of the residuals shouldn't matter AS LONG AS the variable follows a known distribution. Since in my case it is non-gaussian, my question is: is in `auto.arima` the default for "ML" gaussian?

Comment: I think your understanding is incorrect. The unconditional distributions of the variables are irrelevant for MLE. The conditional distribution of the dependent variable which is relevant for MLE coincides with the distribution of the error term, hence we make distributional assumptions on the error term. You need normality of the error term, nothing else. Now `auto.arima` uses Gaussian ML, but some other threads here on CV indicate that it works quite well in nongaussian cases, too (think quasi MLE a.k.a. pseudo MLE).

Comment: Thank you, your last answer gave me some insights :) although I need to do some research on quasi/pseudo MLE.